# 'BlogUpdateView' object has no attribute 'date'

Tags: django-views, django-class-based-views

So i tried Function based views, but still keep getting the same error, anyone that wants to try the error can do so on http://159.65.157.112/
Create an ID, put up a post and go to update

Model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
            

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog-detail', kwargs={'id': self.id})
```

View

```
class BlogUpdateView(UpdateView):
    template_name = "post_update.html"
    form_class = BlogForm

    def get_object(self):
        id_ = self.kwargs.get("id")
        return get_object_or_404(Post, id=id_)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

form

```
class BlogForm(ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=
        {'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Enter title'}
        ))
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=
        {'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Enter content here'}
        ))

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'content']
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone looking for the fix in this one, i got it working by replacing

```
def get_object(self):
    **id_ = self.kwargs.get("id")**
    return get_object_or_404(Post, id=id_)
```

id to pk